# Android REST/JSON Server

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest

I wish to create an Android application which will make use of REST/JSON webservices - with a twist! I wish for the Android device to act as the server, and for the client to be running on a PC.

Does anyone know any good libraries on how I could accomplish this?

For those of you who are curious on what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to make a PC manipulate some functions of an Android smartphone.

If worst came to worst, I could always use raw sockets, however this is my last choice.

Thanks